# Switching JavaFX Scene when RFID-Card is on reader (Arduino)

Tags: java, javafx, arduino, rfid

I am working on a project for school right now and the task is to develope a Desktop-application for a fake hospital.

The application is used to store and display medical records of patients. Therefore it is required to have a login system. For the Login system, we are required to use an Arduino and the included MFRC-522 RFID module. Basically  when a card is scanned, the user should be logged in and he stays logged into his account for as long as the card is on the reader. As soon as he takes off the card, he loggs out of his account.

I already managed to code the Arduinosketch and the bytestream-reader in Java. (I used the JSerialComm library for Java for that).

**My problem right now is:**
I made a UI for the application, but I can't find a way to swap the scene when the Arduino reads a card. So basically, I want the UI to switch from the Loginscene to the mainmenuscene as soon as the card touches the card reader and as soon as the card is taken away from the reader, the loginmenu should be displayed again.

```
package application;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortDataListener;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortEvent;

public class CardReader {

    SerialPort activePort;
    public static boolean LoggedOut = true;
    public static String ID = "";

    public CardReader() {
        activePort = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM3");
        activePort.openPort();
        activePort.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener() {

            @Override
            public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
                int size = event.getSerialPort().bytesAvailable();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                event.getSerialPort().readBytes(buffer, size);
                for (byte b : buffer) {
                    if (b == 10) {
                        CardReader.ID = CardReader.ID.trim();
                        if (CardReader.ID.equals("XXXXX")) {
                            if (LoggedOut == false) {
                                mainClass.LoginManager.logout(mainClass.currentUser);
                                //Show loginmenu
                                System.out.println("logged out");
                                LoggedOut = true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            
                            mainClass.currentUser.setUserID(CardReader.ID);
                            if(mainClass.LoginManager.loginWithCard(mainClass.currentUser, mainClass.listOfAllUsers) == true) {
                                //Here I want to show the mainmenu
                                //I tried to call methods from the LoginController here
                                //directly, but that doesn't work
                                System.out.println("Logged in");
                                System.out.println("|" + CardReader.ID + "|");
                                LoggedOut = false;
                            }else {
                                //Ausgabe Karte gesperrt
                                System.out.println("Karte gesperrt");
                            }
                            
                        }
                            
                        //System.out.println("|" + CardReader.ID.trim() + "|");
                        CardReader.ID = "";
                    } else {
                        CardReader.ID += (char) b;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public int getListeningEvents() {
                return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Code for the Controller of the loginmenu I use to handle the UI

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import application.User.permissions;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LoginController {

    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);

    @FXML
    private TextField TextFieldUsername;
    @FXML
    private TextField TextFieldPassword;

    public void setUIKarte(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoginmenuCard.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public void setUIUser(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoginmenuUser.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

//I use this code for mutiple Scenes, that's why there are also functions 
//for the option to login with a Username and password
    public void loginbuttonclick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        mainClass.currentUser.setUsername(TextField.getText());
        mainClass.aktuellerBenutzer.setPassword(TextFieldPassword.getText());

        if (mainClass.LoginManager.L(mainClass.currentUser,
                mainClass.listOfAllUsers)) {
            setHauptmenu(event, mainClass.currentUser.getUserPerm());
        } else {
            mainClass.LoginManager.lo(mainClass.currentUser);
            alert.setContentText("Username and Password are incorrect.");
            alert.show();
        }

    }

    public void setMainmenu(ActionEvent event, Permissions inPermissions) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("CardMenu.fxml"));;
        
        switch (inPermissions) {
        case ADMIN:
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainmenuAdmin.fxml"));
            break;
        case DOCTOR:
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Mainmenu.fxml"));
            break;
        case NURSE:
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Mainmenu.fxml"));
            break;
        case STAFF:
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Mainmenu.fxml"));
            break;
        case NONE:
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Mainmenu.fxml"));
            break;
        }
        stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public void InvisButtonClick(ActionEvent event) {
        
        
    }

}
```

I tried to call methods from the LoginController class directly, but that doesn't work because the SerialportListener is on another Thread (automatically by the library).

Comment: *"I tried to call methods from the LoginController class directly, but that doesn't work because the SerialportListener is on another Thread"*. I may be misunderstanding the issue, but don't you just need to wrap those calls in `Platform.runLater(...)`?

Comment: Don't try to load any `Scene` in `CardReader`.  Make `CardReader` a `Task`. Use the `Task` `setOnSucceeded` return value to determine if you want to load a `Scene` or not. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm